# How to remove IIS management Machinekey validation key and decryption key

Tags: windows, iis, server

Hello i was seaching around for some time on how i remove from the IIS the validation key and the decryption key. as in the UI i cant see how i remove it.

[image: the settings how it looks]

Answer (score 0):

Because it is only possible to choose from two options,

- Let ASP.NET runtime automatically generate the key(s) at runtime. (aka, leave the check box checked)
- Pre-generate the key(s) and hard code them. (aka, leave the check box unchecked)

and the management UI clearly presents both options to you and expects you to only flip the check boxes. There is no possibility to "remove" anything from there.